# Defining suffix _t data types inside my own namespaces

Tags: c++

The suffix `_t` for types is reserved by POSIX, but what if I define my own types with an `_t` suffix inside my own namespaces?

Comment: May the schwartz be with you.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik so I should use _schwartz instead?

Comment: If it's big enough, yes.

Comment: it should work, if its inside its own namespace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll agree with the [user6366161](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6366161/user6366161)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37369508) where it says "C doesn't know anything about namespaces".  POSIX is primarily a C standard, and the headers it defines are defined for use by C (currently C99 since the last main update to POSIX was in 2008, well before the C 2011 standard was released).  So, when you include a POSIX header into a C++ program, the chances are that all the names introduced are in the global namespace — unless an implementation has done something unexpected.

#### Thesis

If you place your own type names into your own namespace, and you are careful about references to your types and POSIX types within the namespace, then there can be no direct conflict with the POSIX types in the global namespace.

#### Commentary

That it works does not make it a good idea. It is a bad idea to willfully create name collisions with well-known POSIX types, but the technique would protect you against accidental collisions (and collisions with undocumented types in the POSIX reserved namespace).

If, despite the advice against doing so, you decide to use this technique, you would need to be careful — you will cause confusion to casual readers of your code.  Note that when the code within your namespace uses your types without any scope qualifier, it uses your type rather than the POSIX type when the unqualified names collide.  You can use the global scope operator to pick up POSIX type names that conflict with those in your namespace.

#### Illustrative code

Here's an example.  The calculations are pointless — the objective is to play around with the `pid_t` type (an integral type from POSIX) and an alternative type `pid_t` that's in a separate namespace (`NonPosix`) and is an alias for `long double`.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <unistd.h>

namespace NonPosix
{
    typedef long double pid_t;
    pid_t gruesome(pid_t pos);
    void unsightly();
}

#include <iostream>

using NonPosix::gruesome;
namespace { void obnoxious(); }

int main()
{
    pid_t pid = getpid();
    NonPosix::pid_t angle = gruesome(2.0304815L);

    std::cout << "PID = " << pid << "; angle = " << angle << "\n";

    obnoxious();
    NonPosix::unsightly();

    return 0;
}

// The using statement is invalid - pid_t is already defined in the global scope
#ifdef TRY_USING_NONPOSIX_PID_T
using NonPosix::pid_t;
#endif

namespace {

void obnoxious()
{
    pid_t pid = getppid() + 0.71;   // This is an integral type!
    std::cout << "Obnoxious:\n";
    std::cout << "PID = " << pid << "; angle = " << gruesome(pid) << "\n";
}

}

namespace NonPosix
{

pid_t gruesome(pid_t pos)
{
    pid_t apos = pos + 2.22;
    pid_t rval = atan2l(pos, apos);
    std::cout << "Gruesome: POS = " << pos << "; APOS = " << apos
              << "; RVAL = " << rval << "\n";
    return rval;
}

void unsightly()
{
    pid_t pid = getpid() + 0.65;
    std::cout << "Unsightly:\n";
    std::cout << "PID = " << pid << "; angle = " << gruesome(pid);
    ::pid_t ppid = getppid() + 0.29;    // This is an integral type
    std::cout << "; PPID = " << ppid << "\n";
}

}
```

The code is demo code, not production code, but I think it illustrates some points.

#### Example output

```
Gruesome: POS = 2.03048; APOS = 4.25048; RVAL = 0.445654
PID = 7765; angle = 0.445654
Obnoxious:
Gruesome: POS = 670; APOS = 672.22; RVAL = 0.783744
PID = 670; angle = 0.783744
Unsightly:
Gruesome: POS = 7765.65; APOS = 7767.87; RVAL = 0.785255
PID = 7765.65; angle = 0.785255; PPID = 670
```

Most notably, it illustrates my basic thesis:

- Types defined in a user-defined namespace with the `_t` suffix do not directly conflict with POSIX types because the POSIX types are in the global namespace.
- It is not a good idea to make use of such types when the names conflict with a fundamental POSIX type such as `pid_t`.

Answer (score 1):

This is why namespace come into play, just do it.

At worst, your defined a type the same with posix defines, your use your defined in your namespace, and you also can reference posix defines with ::posix_type_t.

Comment: c++ defined the name lookup rules, in you namespace  your types will gets priority over others. see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lookup

Answer (score 0):

C doesn't know anything about namespaces. If you include a POSIX header file, it's going to pollute the global namespaces with its types. Putting your own type into a namespace isn't going to fix anything.

Comment: even if I include c++ version of that header file? e.g <cstdio>?

Comment: @Ark `<cstdio>` is a C++ header. And whether or not those names go into the global namespace or `std` is unspecified.

Answer (score 0):

Implementations of POSIX are supposed to provide feature selection macros. If you have, say:

```
-D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=201112
```

then no `_t` types introduced after 2011-12 should be visible to your code. In fact, nothing newer than the requested POSIX API version.

(Everyone except for a few BSD, Cygwin and Apple people understands how feature selection macros are supposed to work).

If you have the proper feature selection in place, you can safely ignore this nonsense about `_t` (a ridiculously common coding convention used by C programmers everywhere) being reserved for the sole use of POSIX.

C typedef names do not have linkage (external or internal) so if the preprocessor hides the declaration of a typedef, then it essentially doesn't exist; you can declare your own typedef of the same name.

If you follow this practice and somehow still get a clash, then just deal with that clash. Rename your clashing type to something else and move on.

Comment: IMO, POSIX [disagrees](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_02_02) with you.  _Implementations may add symbols to the headers shown in the following table, provided the identifiers for those symbols either: … or 3) End in the string indicated as a reserved suffix in the table …_ and one of the suffixes is `_t` and it is reserved if any of the POSIX headers (which include the C standard headers) is included.  I take that to mean that (within extremely broad limits) any identifier ending in `_t` can be used as an additional type by the implementation.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler This is all rather moot. Before, say, `aio_read` was introduced, how would programmers have known not to use it? POSIX will introduce identifiers into whatever identifier spaces it wants. Part of your program will get bulldozed and you just have to rebuild a few meters to the right.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Also, implementations should provide feature selection macros for revealing their extensions. If Scrotely Unix defines some blarg_t type in <stdlib.h>, that should be hidden unless we have -D_SCROTELY_UNIX_SOURCE or whatever.  If not, then complain to Scrotely Unix to clean up their headers and conform to the proper way of using feature selection macros.